# C# streamwriter invoke

Tags: c#, invoke, streamwriter

i want to reach and write a txt file in cross-threads but software gives an exception because multiple threads wants to reach the same file at the same time. How can i invoke streamwriter to avoid exceptions? Here is my code:

```
void WriteLog(string LogStr)
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Log.txt", true);
    sw.WriteLine(LogStr);
    sw.Close();
}
```

I call WriteLog method in threads.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the use of something like NLog or log4net out of the question? This will solve the issue for you as they handle all these complexities. As an aside, opening and closing a file every time you want to log a message will cause you major headaches in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use a Mutex:

```
private Mutex mut = new Mutex(); // Somewhere in mail class
void WriteLog(string LogStr)
{
    mut.WaitOne();
    try 
    {
        using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Log.txt", true))
            sw.WriteLine(LogStr);
    } 
    finally 
    {
        mut.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Mutex` class:

```
Mutex mut = new Mutex();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you don't wanna wait for log (sounds only logical) you should just push the log message to a synchronized queue (available from .net 4) and let a background thread handle all log writes. If you'll use mutex and locks it'll hit your performance. in memory queue writing is much faster then file writing.